# What is sun.awt.image.BufImgSurfaceData?

Tags: java, graphics

Attempting to track down a potential graphics related performance issue, a heapdump was executed via JVisualVM.

Opened the dump within Eclipse Memory Analyzer and one of the "Problem Suspects" 
 is shown as the following :

[image]

Searching the code and there is no direct reference to BufImgSurfaceData being used. 
Doing a google search doesn't reveal much info about the class as well.

Where can information about this Class be found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where can information about this Class be found?

By reading the OpenJDK source code ... which anyone can download for themselves, for free.  (The following is from the Java 8 source code.)

The class has minimal comments, but it extends `sun.java2d.SurfaceData` whose javadoc comment block say this:

```
/**
 * This class provides various pieces of information relevant to a
 * particular drawing surface.  The information obtained from this
 * object describes the pixels of a particular instance of a drawing
 * surface and can only be shared among the various graphics objects
 * that target the same BufferedImage or the same screen Component.
 * <p>
 * Each SurfaceData object holds a StateTrackableDelegate object
 * which tracks both changes to the content of the pixels of this
 * surface and changes to the overall state of the pixels - such
 * as becoming invalid or losing the surface.  The delegate is
 * marked "dirty" whenever the setSurfaceLost() or invalidate()
 * methods are called and should also be marked "dirty" by the
 * rendering pipelines whenever they modify the pixels of this
 * SurfaceData.
 * <p>
 * If you get a StateTracker from a SurfaceData and it reports
 * that it is still "current", then you can trust that the pixels
 * have not changed and that the SurfaceData is still valid and
 * has not lost its underlying storage (surfaceLost) since you
 * retrieved the tracker.
 */
```

From this, it seems that `sun.awt.image.BufImgSurfaceData` is involved in performing draw operations on a `BufferedImage` object, and associated things.

(That is pretty high level, but it should be sufficient for you to figure out if this is relevant to your performance issue.  I suspect it isn't, unless there is a lot of "churn" of `BufferedImage` objects.)